# Motor does not move with 4 batteries

Tags: power, motor, battery

I mada a  4wd car with ultrasonic sensors and servo. I use 4 AA 1.5 volt batteries for power. But the motor does not move. What is the problem?

[image]

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Schematic where?

Comment: I just added the above

Comment: you have to run a program

Comment: The L298 is a horrible chip, if you want to use that you'll probably have to add two cells to the battery pack just to account for its losses.  Note that you seem to be following a guide that recommends 6 cells, while you have only used 4.

Comment: When you say "the motor does not move", are you referring to the four DC motors, or the servo motor?

Comment: Thank you everyone. I have replaced the battery with 18650 (3.7 v). And it worked

Comment: If Aamir's answer helped you please vote it up and/or accept it, so people know that was the issue.

Answer (score 2):

In the future, please detail your attempts at solving the problem so far so we can help you better.

Approach the issue as methodically as possible. I don't know how familiar you are with electronics, so please excuse me if you think some of these questions are basic:

1. Ensure that the servo motor works first without any other motors or
   sensors connected to the Arduino Sensor Shield (have you used this servo motor before?)
2. Ensure that your GVS wiring is in the correct order. Servos come with a 3 way socket that plug straight onto the Sensor Shield: G goes to the Brown or Black wire, V goes to the (middle) Red wire, S goes to the Orange wire. The good news is as the +5V is in the middle, things will not blow up if you put the 3-pin plug on the wrong way. The servo just will not work until you plug it in correctly.
3. Is the Arduino Sensor shield working correctly. Does the LED pin work? Do other signals sent from the board work?
4. Remember that servo motors work differently to normal DC motors. You need to use [Pulse Width Modulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation) to set the position. If you have never done this before, you will find the [Arduino Servo Motors](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Servo) page useful. Also, you will get some excellent understanding and code from this [Adafruit page](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-motor-shield-v2-for-arduino). It is for a different Arduino shield, but the principles are the same.

Comment: The question seems more likely to be about the drive motors than the servo.

Comment: Ah. I hope my effort isn't wasted then. I guess it happens sometime. I've asked the author to clarify. Thanks for your detailed, helpful contributions to StackExchange Arduino. I just read some of your posts, and they are very helpful.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I have replaced the battery with 18650 (3.7 v). And it worked

Comment: @Riski, if you found any of the answers helpful, feel free to show your appreciation by selecting the answer and upvoting helpful answers. This is how the StackExchange system works: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up

Answer (score 0):

Use a LiPo battery I.e 2S(7.4V)